# On the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us consider a definite postive matrix $A$ with a large eigenvalue denoted by $\overline{\lambda}$ and denote by $\langle, \rangle$ the inner scalar of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Do we have the following statement:
$$ |\langle Ax,y\rangle | \; \leq \overline{\lambda}|\langle x,y\rangle|, \forall x,y  \in \mathbb{R}^n.$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true. Consider, for instance, in $\Bbb R^3$ where
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}a & - a & 0\\a & a & 0\\0&0&\sqrt2a\end{bmatrix}
$$
for some $a\gg 1$, which is rotating $45^\circ$ around the $z$-axis, then scale by a factor of $\sqrt2 a$ (which makes $\bar \lambda = \sqrt2 a$ and $[0,0,1]^T$ a corresponding eigenvector). This is positive definite.

However, with $x = [1, 0, 0]^T$ and $y = [0,1, 0]^T$, we get
$$
\langle Ax, y\rangle = a\\
\langle x, y\rangle = 0
$$
The moral is that even if $\bar \lambda$ might be a bound on how much larger $A$ can make a vector (if you want it to be an actual bound, regardless of whether $Ax$ and $x$ are parallel, then that is called the *operator norm* and is slightly more general than "largest eigenvalue"), it doesn't stop $A$ from making orthogonal vectors be non-orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what happens if we consider $n=2$?

Comment: @HoussainePhilou Then you can use $A = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}a & a\\0 & a\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $x, y$ being the standard basis vectors.

Comment: In fact I'm interested in symetric matrices ?

Comment: @HoussainePhilou Then how about $A = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}a & 1\\1 & a\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, with the same $x$ and $y$?

Comment: I see, the problem is that $<x,y>$ could be zero. Anyway, thank you four you discussion.

Comment: If we assume that $|<x,y>| \leq \eta <1 $, do we still have $$ |<Ax,y>| \leq \overline{\lambda} \; \eta $$

Comment: @HoussainePhilou No, take $\eta = 0$ and look at all my examples again.

Answer (score 0):

For any vector $x$, there is $x = v_1 + \dots + v_n$ and $v_i ( i = 1,\dots,n)$ is the eigenvector of matrix $A$. Then, there exist that

$\langle Ax,y \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i \langle v_i,y \rangle $. If $\langle v_i,y \rangle \geq0$ for any $i$, it has the following statement:

$\sum_{i=1}^{p} \lambda_i \langle v_i,y \rangle \leq \bar{\lambda}\sum_{i=1}^{p} \langle v_i,y \rangle =\bar{\lambda} \langle x,y \rangle $ where the $\bar{\lambda}$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A$.

However, $R^n = span\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$. It seems that it is impossible to make $\langle v_i,y \rangle > 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: Yes, you are right ! Thank you.

Comment: You are assuming that $A$ is diagonalisable when you claim that you can write $x$ as a sum of eigenvectors (that's what diagonalisable means). This is not always true. If $A$ is symmetric, then it is diagonalisable, and according to the comments under my answer, this might be the case. Also, please use `\langle` and `\rangle` for angle brackets; they look _much_ better than `<` and `>`, especially when you use them in inequalities. Finally, you can make $\langle v_i, y\rangle>0$ for all $i$, for instance if $A = I$ and $y = [1, 1]^T$ with $v_1 = [1,0]^T$ and $v_2 = [0,1]^T$.